# How to create list with float values in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am a beginner in this field, I want to create a list of float values in kotlin
Example: In python

```
myList=[]

mylist.append(1.5)

mylist.append(2.5)
```

but how to do this in kotlin

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collections-overview.html#list

Answer (score 2):

We need to specify the list element's data type (`Float` in this case) when initializing empty mutable list using `mutableListOf()`.

```
val myList = mutableListOf<Float>()
myList.add(1.5f)
myList.add(2.5f)
```

Comment: Is it possible to add both integer and float values in a single list?

Comment: `val myList = mutableListOf<Number>()` but that won't allow common arithmetic operations on the list. It would be better to instead use `mutableListOf<Float>()` itself to store both Int and Float.

Comment: Better to use an immutable list unless you need the mutability for some reason: `val myList = listOf(1.5f, 2.5f)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`listOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/list-of.html) function:

```
val listOfFloats: List<Float> = listOf(1.1f, 2.2f, 3.3f)
```

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin you can make a list like this

```
var myList: List<Int> = listOf<Int>(1, 2, 7, 9);
```

But if you want to push an item to the list you need to make it a mutable list. So I would say that you use a MutableList instead of a List

So it looks like this

```
var myList : MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf<Int>(); //You can add initial values inside the parentheses
myList.add(10);
myList.add(20);
```

Comment: This is true, but the question was about `Float`s, not `Int`s. Also you can do things like `listOf(1,2) + 3` to work with immutable lists without resorting to mutability.